# Oauth Consumer key/secret vs access_token/access_secret

Tags: oauth, twitter-oauth

I'm trying to understand what each string in the Oauth 1 scheme does.
As per my understanding, the consumer key and consumer secret are used to sign a request to the api, from the calling application, and the access_token and access_secret pair are used as a proxy for the user's login credentials.

Am I right in my understanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite. The consumer key is a value that identifies the client application that is being used to access the user resources, and the access token is the value that provides the authorization to access those resources.

A combination of the consumer secret and token secret are used to sign the request which provides verification that the request is being sent by an authorized party.

You can read more about the definitions of the [oauth 1.0a spec](http://oauth.net/core/1.0a/#anchor3) here.